# Cant use any functions [Type error] Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

The error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add') line 40

I looked everywhere like even in the discord API but nothing. If there is anything I can do better in my code tell me.

If it's necessary I use VSC and node.js.

The `member` is a variable and used in if() in the code but it doesn't work.

```js
const { Client , GatewayIntentBits} = require('discord.js')
require('dotenv/config')
var not_stable = "⭕"
var working = ""
var done = "✅"
var failed = "❌"


const client = new Client({
    intents:[
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    ],
})

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("Bot is ready :D");
})

client.on("messageCreate", message => {

    if(message.author == client.user) {
        return;
    }
    
    var member = message.mentions.users.first();
    var channel = message.channel;
    var bug_channel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(r => r.id === "1030971519754588200");
    var sup = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name == "Suporter")
    var ping_sup = "<@&"+sup.id+"> "

    if (message.content == "op <@"+member.id+">") {
        if (member != undefined) {
            let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === "1030196677472178298");
            try {
                console.log(member)
                member.roles.add(role); //my problem is at the add its not defined
            } 
            catch(error) {
                bug_channel.send(ping_sup+"Error while: \n"+error);
            }
            message.reply("BETA");
            message.react(not_stable);
        }

        if (member === undefined) {
            message.reply("There is no user in your command");
            message.react(failed);
        }
    }   
    
    if (message.content === "ping") {
        message.reply("PAMINHING pong");
        message.react(done);
    }

    if (message.content === "timeout <@"+member.id+">") {
        if (member === undefined) {
            message.reply("Please do it manually");
            message.react(failed)
        }
        else {
            member.timeout(5 * 60 * 1000, 'Time to take a break');
            message.reply("Timed out for 5min");
            message.react(done);
        }
    }

    if (message.content === "ids") {
        message.reply("This is under construction and doesn't work");
    }
})

client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

The error is always that noting after `member.` is recognised and I don't find the solution I'm new to js. ya thx for ya help :D

Comment: What this logs? `console.log(member)`

Comment: just to see the member id in the log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your `member` variable is not a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember), but a [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User). You try to get the roles of a `User`, but only `GuildMembers` have roles.

To fix this, you can use `message.mentions.members.first()` instead as [`message.mentions.members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=members) returns a `GuildMember`:

```js
var member = message.mentions.members.first();
```